# On which site should I ask questions related to computer security?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I want to know how to respond to an attack to a webmail account. Which is the correct site to ask?

I tried superuser.com but apparently, [I'm wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/283203/how-can-a-hacker-access-a-yahoo-account). Webmasters?

Comment: Hmm, I'd have been wrong too, it seems. In fact, I *still* think Super User is the appropriate place to ask such a question. Computer security would also be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but only if it relates to programming. This doesn't.

Comment: The IT Security site's [FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq) says: "IT Security - Stack Exchange is for is for **Information Security professionals** to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include web app hardening, network security, phishing, risk management, policies, penetration testing, tools and using cryptography. **If you are a home user you may be better served by asking your question at superuser.com**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the question, maybe [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) ? There is also [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), but that may not be the best place for a webmail issue.

Comment: Thanks; after seeing http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/anonymous-links-in-email, I'll try ITS.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not written down in their [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) only accepts computer questions if

- the computer is in front of you, not someone else's computer
- the computer is a desktop or laptop, or possibly a server, but not a PDA or mobile phone or other portable device, nor an embedded computer with no direct interface. (There's an exception: home routers are ok.)

You've run afoul of the first unwritten guideline: on the surface, you're asking about Yahoo's computers. Usually mentioning a web site will get your question closed on SU, whether the web site is the source of the problem or not. Actually, it's likely that the link exploited a browser bug, and browser issues are on-topic on SU, so SU was the right place for your question.

[Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is the right place to ask about applications that are running on a web server and that you're interfacing with with your web browser. However, in your case, the issue is likely with the browser and not related to the particular web application, which would make it off-topic.

[IT Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is for security professionals. Your question is borderline there: discussing the mechanisms of security attacks is ok, but if you don't speak the professionals' language ([“discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities”](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq)), your question is unlikely to be well-received.

Comment: If it's "not written down in their FAQ", how are we to know these topical requirements for Super User? Are you merely speaking from empirical evidence, or is there a discussion on the site meta that covered this? You present the stipulations as if they're official when you've plainly said that they're not.

Comment: @Cody: Source: personal observation, when I was active on SU (Aug–Nov 2010). I'd lobby for these rules to be changed (reconcile usage with the tagline), or failing that documented (reconcile the FAQ with the usage), but I've never managed to get any of the SU moderators to understand that the FAQ is misleading. Feel free to raise the issue on Meta.SU, I've lost motivation.

Comment: Understood. I don't use the site enough to be able to intelligently campaign. I was just wondering how you knew that. I've always thought SU was a bit too broad in its charter and that the community would be better served by some more targeted attempts to clarify that by active, long-time users. Regardless, your input here is appreciated, +1.

Comment: I don't understand where it's not mentioned in the FAQ. It clearly states: `and it is not about … 1.videogames or consoles 2. websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress 3. electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer 4. a shopping or buying recommendation` @CodyGray

Comment: @Sathya: You probably find it clear because your default definition of “computer” agrees with it. For SU's intended audience, anything done through the computer is a “computer question”, even if it happens to be communicating with a PDA or website. The most problematic case is browser questions, which are almost always closed on SU if they happen to mention a website, even though they are questions about web browsers. Example: the question that triggered this discussion, probably a browser issue, unlikely to have anything to do with the website that was mentioned.

Comment: @Gilles - I disagree about browser questions being almost closed if they mention a website. If they're closed - it's because it's something they wish to achieve with the website than the browser.